# ZMQ, PUB/SUB, lost messages when "sleep" is removed

Tags: c, zeromq, publish-subscribe

We have a small code snippet to push messages from a SQLite database (import as a shared object file). zMQ is used to push some data like row ID, table name etc. but there is a problem with the communication when a "sleep" is removed from the code.

The code snippet is having e structure to fit the sqlite database client.

```
void callback (void *user_data,int op,char const *dbn,char const *tn, sqlite3_int64 row_id)
{
    char* optext = "";
    char zmq_string[80];
    int string_length;
    char* connection;
    int linger = 1000;

    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *sender =  zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_PUB);

    connection = "tcp://localhost:"  "7676";
    zmq_setsockopt(sender, ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof (linger));
    zmq_connect (sender, connection);
    string_length = sprintf(zmq_string, "{\"row\":\"%lld\",\"table\":\"%s\"}", (long long)row_id, tn);
    //sleep(1);

    zmq_send (sender, zmq_string, string_length, 0);
    //sleep(1);
    zmq_close (sender);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
}
```

When I have the sleep-call everything works fine, but without nothing is sent.
So I tried to use the LINGER-command. But it does not seem to change the behaviour. Tried to set the LINGER parametr both before and after calling connect without success.

The purpose of the code is to, as fast as possible, execute and send the message and return to the database client. We do not have the time to sleep in this callback.

Comment: Does the sleep(), or whatever,  really matter that much when you are carrying round the dead weight of a connect/disconnect protocol?  Your performance is going to be hopelessly bad anyway.

Comment: Might be so, but this is what I currently have and I cannot change anything at this moment. With the PAIR-protocol we had good enough performance for out embedded device, but I have to channge it to pub/sub due to multiple publishers..

Comment: have you tried to log return values from zmq functions calls?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `zmq_send` is asyncronous, it doesnt actually send the message. It is copied into buffers inside the socket/context and sent later. If you destroy the context/socket right after calling send then it'll likely kill the message before its sent.

If this is supposed to be fast then you really dont want to be creating a context and socket every time. Creating a zeromq context will create at least one thread.

You probably want to create a context and socket elsewhere and just call send within the callback. The socket pointer could go in/be the userdata?

Comment: Yes of course it would be better to create the context and socket somewhere else, but I don't know how to when it comes to extensions for sqlite. Currently I am working on an mqtt solution instead. Some tests shows that (in python) one connect, send and destroy can be done in about 15ms. Which is good enough for this device. With zmq I have the same numbers, without any data actually sent. :(

Comment: If your registering the callback then you can pass in a socket at that point as user data?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it was a long time ago i Built C programs, and extensions to SQLite is not in my area, so i don't know how to pass in a socket in the exteions.

Comment: I found that using PUSH/PULL instead of pub/sub solved my problem. One  iteration takes about 5ms in average (on my personal computer) which is OK for our device.